# Custom controller tool for Maya using Python

Tags: python, controller, maya

I was hoping someone could please help me fix my create_controllers method. I'm trying to create a custom controller tool for use within Maya using Python and unfortunately I'm still trying to learn Python. I need to create a method that creates a controller for every joint that is selected and for every child joint under the joint selected and creates a group if the group controllers checkbox is checked all of which will be parented under the parent of the selected joints once created. Sorry if that's too confusing...I'm willing to dumb it down. Here is my code, I just need help fixing the create_controller method. Thank you in advance!

Edit: code has been trimmmed...this is what I have so far but trying to figure it out. If someone could help me figure out how to write this method I would appreciate it!

def create_controller(self, shape, suffix):
selection = cmds.ls(selection=True)
if not selection:
cmds.warning("Please select at least one joint.")
return

```
    for joint in selection:
        if self.checkbox_group.isChecked(empty=True):    
            if shape == "circle":
                cmds.circle(name=joint + suffix)
            else:
                cmds.warning("Invalid controller shape.")
                return
            cmds.group(empty=True, name=joint, + "_grp")
            cmds.parent(controller, group)
            cmds.select(controller, replace=True)
        if not self.checkbox_group(empty=False):
            if shape == "circle":
                cmds.circle(name=joint + suffix)
            else:
                cmds.warning("Invalid controller shape.")
                return    
            cmds.select(controller, replace=True)
```

I've been working with copilot and chatgpt for days trying to get the code to work by fixing it but I'm stuck.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).